# how to add new li permanently to jquery ribbon?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating ribbon menu in PHP application with jQuery.

I am using this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-officebar/ to create ribbon menu.

Ribbon menu is created in my application but the need is when you create on one menu item than it should be opened in to an another tab. and after that we need to be able to close that tab separately.

The ribbon menu is created with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. i tried to add one new `li` `onclick` of menu item. the code for this is :

```
$("#testRibbon ul").append('<li class="current"><span>Message Center</span></li>');
```

But I couldn't fix this `li`. means when the page is refreshed than that `li` is been removed.

Can anyone tell me that how add a new `li` to ribbon menu's `ul` ?

Comment: When you refresh the page, the page will again start showing what is sent as response. So, whatever you added through jquey will go away.

Comment: I don't really fully understand the question but the way I see it, you are expecting the added li tags to remain as is when the page is reloaded. That will not happen because the li tags are dynamically added onclick. It is natural for the browser to reset your page on refresh. If you want them to remain, you may want to make use of some server scripting. You can also achieve this by using AJAX.

Comment: How can i achieve this by AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#testRibbon > ul").append('<li><a href="#" rel="my-rel" >Message Center</a></li>');
```

Comment: Thanks arun. But it gives me same result.

Answer (score 0):

My reply to your comment (How to do this in AJAX):

this is a messy way to do it but this gives you the result that (I Think) u want :

index.php :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX</title>
        <style>
            .obj {
                padding:15px 15px;
                background:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="obj">Click Me</div>

        <ul class="items">
        </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

            //Retrieve current SESSION li tags

            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'ajax.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(json, function(i, serverData) {
                        $('.items').append('<li class="item">' + serverData + '</li>');
                    });
                }

            });

            //add li tags and store to session

            var counter = 0;
            $('.obj').on('click', function() {

                counter++;
                $('.items').append('<li class="item">Foo' + counter + '</li>');

                var form_data,
                    li_array = new Array();

                $('.item').each(function() {
                    li_array.push( $(this).html() );
                });

                form_data = {
                    data : li_array
                };

                //set.php sets the SESSION data and appends the li tags to it for future reference
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'set.php',
                    data : form_data
                });

            });

        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ajax.php :

```
<?php
session_start();

echo json_encode($_SESSION['li']);

?>
```

set.php :

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['li'] = array();

foreach ($_POST['data'] as $data) { array_push($_SESSION['li'], $data); }

echo json_encode($_SESSION['li']);

?>
```

NOTE : This will retain the li tags. The way to abolish them is to clear the sessions.